# How to find the possible solutions of a trigonometric function, getting the equivalent cotangent result of a fraction?

Tags: trigonometry

I just want to ask on how do you specifically get the possible solutions of $\cot x = \frac{1}{\sqrt3}$? Do you need a basis for this on a unit circle or can you manually identify the solutions for it?

This is the part where I get confused sometimes since having a basis from the book that I have (Trigonometry (10th Edition) by Margaret L. Lial, John Hornsby, David I. Schneider, Callie Daniels), it only directly gives the possible solutions without explaining how it was acquired.

> Solve $\cot x - \sqrt3 = \csc x$ over the interval $[0, 2\pi$):
> $$(\cot x - \sqrt3)^2 = \csc^2 x$$
> $$\cot^2 x - 2 \sqrt3 \cot x + 3 = \csc^2 x = 1 + \cot^2x$$
> $$-2 \sqrt3 \cot x = -2$$
> $$\cot x = \frac{1}{\sqrt3} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}.$$

Now, $\frac{\sqrt3}{3}$ is more likely equivalent to $\cot \pi/3$ and $\cot 4\pi/3$ (since the book states it) , I just want to know how do I identify or get the cot equivalent of $\frac{\sqrt3}{3}$ which was $\cot \pi/3$ and $\cot 4\pi/3$, how was it identified?

Your responses would be highly appreciated. Thank you very much!!

Comment: You can learn how to type mathematics using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). This is better than using pictures as people with disabilities can now read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $\frac\pi3$ and $\frac{4\pi}3$—in fact, $(\frac\pi3+n\pi)$ for each integer $n$— are solutions of $\cot x,$ due to its cyclic nature.

(This cyclic nature is apparent from either [the graph of $\cot$](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=graph+of+cotangent), or from observing that $\tan,$ and thus $\cot,$ attains the same value as the corresponding point on the unit circle rotates every $180^\circ.$)

Your given question restricts the solution interval to $[0,2\pi),$ so the solution set comprises both your suggested solutions.

Answer (score 1):

$\cot{x} = \frac{1}{\tan x}$ when $\tan x \ne 0$. So taking the reciprocal of both sides, $\tan x = \frac{3}{\sqrt{3}} = \sqrt{3}$.